# Use gray scale images to train Haar Classifier

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, machine-learning, kinect

Hi everyboy I am using visual studio 2010 with Kinect and opencv!! I have a question about Harr classifier!!Well I want to recognize a object that has a lot of sizes but I do not care its color!!for that reason I want to train Haar Classifier with gray scale images and when I show a object in front kinect, convert that frame in gray scale image in order my sotfware detect that is objects that was trained!! Is that a good idea?? Because object have a lot of sizes and colors!And I want to eliminate color!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience with opencv haarcascades you should always convert to grey-scale and then equalise your histogram before proceeding.

Comment: ooohh yaap!! And mmm well But My object have a different color in the morning that in night!!So my object will have different scale gray!!I dont know If I must train haar classifier with images in the nigh or there is a method to convert all images with the same constrast or another method to deal with that!!

Comment: What is your object? Might be able to help you more if I knew.

Comment: My object is an apple!Apple have a different sizes and different shades of red color and there are green apple with different sizes and different shades of green color!!

Comment: Heyy Jonathan!! is a good idea to train haar cascade with positive and negatives grayscale images and positive images with background, only object that I want to detect=?

Comment: Interesting... Because apples have a lot of different textures might make it tricky. I would definitely train with negatives. Try and normalise you images as best as possible centre them and make sure they cover the same area... I would include no background if possible

Comment: Yes It is very difficult and very interesting!!Can you explain me " Try and normalise you images as best as possible centre them and make sure they cover the same area" please??? and I want to use positive images and negatives images in grayscale is a good idea??

Comment: Sure.. by normalise I mean make sure each training image is the same resolution and that the apples occupy the same area for each case....moreover make sure that the centre of each apple is in the same place. You should definitely use positives and negatives otherwise it will not 'learn' to distinguish each case.

Comment: No way!!I took photo of apple that doesnt occupy the same area!But that is too bad?

Comment: I took my positive imgaes in different angles and background!!Is it bad idea?

Comment: You can always somewhat fix these issues with photoshop.

Comment: ok.I have another question!!I read that with createsamples.exe utility you can create more positive images combining positive+negatives images and rotation etc. I took 4000 imgaes of amples without using that utility. Is it necessary to create more samples with this utility?

Comment: Heyy Can you explain me what maxdepth parameter is in opencv_traincascade??

Comment: For you first question... no its not 100% necessary but more training data is better to some extent. For your 2nd... do you know the concept of boosting... Haar cascades are weak tree learners, so the depth is how many children a tree may have, 1 would mean a stump with no children... i think

Comment: Yes sorry I read about boosting yesterday but I have the final question, I am use my program in a embedded system so I want to know what kind of feature extraction(haar, lbp or hog) can I use ??What do you recommend me and why?